# API call from GitHub Pages

Tags: node.js, express, github, github-pages, api-doc

I've created a ReST API implementation using ExpressJS and MongoDB. Currently I am hosting the API on OpenShift. I have generated a documentation using apiDoc and I'm hosting the documentation on GitHub Pages.

When I open the documentation on my local machine it seems to work fine and I get content served from API instance on OpenShift. But when I try to make a call from the one hosted on GitHub Pages, I get the following error:

```
Error 0: 
undefined
```

URL: https://faxad.github.io/xpress/#api-Inventory-GetItems

If I put the URL to the end point in POSTMAN, I get the results OK.

API: http://xpress-xpress-api.7e14.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com/inventory

Why is it not working when I'm trying to access it from GitHub Pages?

Comment: Check your development console. The API is loaded over HTTP while GitHub requires HTTPS connections.

Comment: Thanks.

Working fine after configuring TLS route.

Comment: Hey how did you configure TLS route? Also can we make API calls with github pages?